# local git repository with two remote git repositories

Tags: github, heroku-cli

On my local git repo, I used to push it to two different remote repo, one on github and another on heroku. Now my local is stuck on heroku repo and I want to create a branch from github master branch. How can I change from heroku to github(origin)? [image]

[thi is what my terminal looks like]

Answer (score 0):

See here - you want to set your local branch to track a different remote: [Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)